# Matlab: Detect number of input arguments for function handle from outside of the function

Tags: matlab

I begin with a symbolic function of one variable, calculate the symbolic derivatives of orders 1 through N, and then convert those symbolic functions into function handles and store the function handles in a cell array. I then evaluate each function handle at the same input value using a loop. The problem I have is that it is possible for one of the derivatives to be a constant (with higher order derivatives being zero, of course). As I was trying to give each function handle an input, I face the "Too many input arguments" error. I would like to be able to check, in advance, whether the function handle is a constant so I can avoid the error, but I can't figure out how to do that.

In case a small working example is helpful, I provide the following

```
symVar = sym('symVar');
startFunc = symVar^4 + symVar^3 + symVar^2;
derivesCell = cell(5);
for J=1:5
    derivesCell(J) = {matlabFunction(diff(startFunc,symVar,J))};
end

cumSum = 0;
evalPoint = 2;
for J=1:5
    cumSum = cumSum + derivesCell{J}(evalPoint);
end
```

Execution produces "Error using symengine>@()2.4e1
Too many input arguments."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr:** You can do this with `nargin`:

```
>> nargin(derivesCell{5})
ans =
     0

>> nargin(derivesCell{3})
ans =
     1
```

---

**Explanation:**
Most people are familiar with the use of `nargin` as a "special variable" inside the function, but it can be used outside the context of a function definition, as a function that takes a function_handle argument, returning the number of input arguments that function handle takes. From the documentation:

> NARGIN(FUN) returns the number of declared inputs for the
>       M-file function FUN.  The number of arguments is negative if the
>       function has a variable number of input arguments.  FUN can be 
>       a function handle that maps to a specific function, or a string 
>       containing the name of that function.

Comment: That was my experience. All the examples I saw of `nargin` were always from within the function.

Comment: Also, just pointing out you probably meant to say `derivesCell = cell(5,1)`. What you created is a 5-by-5 cell instead (which might cause you problems at some point if you expect to be indexing horizontally and you're actually indexing vertically, or if you try to get the size of the cell array expecting 5 elements, or something along those lines)